# How to resolve conflict between endpoints?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Let's say I have two endpoints:

```
[HttpGet ("{serialNumber}")]
```

and

```
[HttpGet ("summary")].
```

As a result, my application perceives api/summary as api/{serialNumber} where {serialNumber} = "summary" and I get the wrong behavior that I want.

Comment: simple: use non-ambiguous routes? like `[HttpGet("sn/{serialNumber}")]`. also: i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Is this the only solution? There is another project on which everything is the same, but at the same time it works as it should.

Comment: while it is possibly not the _only_ solution - depending on the format of your serial number you can typehint, for example - it is the *best* solution. it is clean. it is indifferent to the format of the data. it is understandable. (and if it works in another project - look at that that one is doing. if you can't figure it out, ask whoever wrote it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it on my machine with different sdks: net3.1, .net5 and .net6
... working as expected.

```cs
[HttpGet("values/summary")]
public IActionResult GetSummary()
{
   return Ok(new ValueObject[] { new ValueObject { Value = "SUMMARY" } });
}

[HttpGet("values/{serialNumber}")]
public IActionResult GetBySerial([FromRoute] string serialNumber)
{
   return Ok(new ValueObject[] { new ValueObject { Value = serialNumber } });
}
```

If I now call `/values/summary` the result is

```json
{
  "value": "SUMMARY"
}
```

else if I call `/values/abcde` the result is

```json
{
  "value": "abcde"
}
```

So in my opinion if you never have a `{serialNumber} == 'summary'` this APIs should work in the correct way.

If you have possibly the case of a `'summary' == {serialNumber}` use explicit endpoints instead like described before (@Serge).

Answer (score 0):

the only way to resolve it you have to add action name in the route

```
[HttpGet ("GetSerialNumber/{serialNumber}")] 
public ActionResult GetSerialNumber(string serialNumber)

and 

[HttpGet ("GetSummary/{summary}")] 
public ActionResult GetSummary(string summary)
```